# Select audio files created with native Voice Memo app within iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'd like to have users of an app upload voice memos they've recorded on their iPhone.

Is it possible to select audio files created by the native iOS Voice Memo app in a similar way to selecting photos or videos using UIImagePicker.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current versions of `iOS`, it's impossible. But you can simply use `AVAudioRecorder` to record directly. And then upload these voice recorded by your app.